# How to make nginx virtual directories accessible in php?

Tags: php, nginx

Let's say I have a web server (nginx) `server.com` where I have only one php file `index.php` (there is no directory structure). I want to be able to access anything after server.com. It will be an url structure. For example server.com/google.com, server.com/yahoo.com.au etc...

An example would be `http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com` (They don't have a directory that's called */google.com*, right?)

**Q1:** How can I access whatever is after 'server.com' from *index.php*

**Q2:** Can I get the protocol from such URL? For example `server.com/http://www.google.com` or `server.com/https://www.google.com`

**PS**
I'm not certain if the term *virtual directory* is used here correctly. I just want to do what I saw somewhere else.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to emulate Apache's mod_rewrite in order to do "clean" URLs?  So that, for example. `http://example.com/foo/bar` will be served by `/index.php?q=foo/bar`?

Comment: I think so, I didn't know what the name for it was. But I want the original url to stay the same - `http://example.com/foo/bar` is that possible?

Comment: I think we may still need more details.  Are you saying that you would like index.php to act as a *proxy*, so that, for example, someone can visit `http://example.com/https://www.example.net/` and get an INSECURE connection to your server which will make a SECURE connection to example.net?  If so, your question involves PHP programming, not just nginx configuration.

Comment: And to build on the proxy question, if `www.example.net` contains embedded images, do you want your index.php to translate *those* URLs as well, or just pass them through verbatim?  Is this an attempt to hide your browser's IP, or something else?

Comment: I am not building a proxy. php will "only" check if the connection to the specified server is available. Something like `http://www.isup.me/google.com`

Comment: Hey @Radek, don't forget to award your [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)!  Those points don't go back into your account if you forget the award.  The bounty doesn't have to be awarded to the same person who got the "right answer" checkmark.  You've got some excellent answers here, and a couple that go above and beyond the call of duty! I recommend awarding based on effort.  It encourages people to make more of an effort.  :)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I have troubles to award bounty. I want to split it over three people.... I learnt something from all of them...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1
}

location = /index.php {
    #Do your normal php passing stuff here now
}
```

Is that what you were looking for?

As an answer to your second question, you can parse the protocol in php. Nginx doesn't need to do that. To parse the url, you can use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function

Comment: Sigh.  That's the answer.  +1

Comment: I have to test it over the weekend. Well the protocol user can specify  could be different to the one my server uses. Let's say nginx runx on http but user types `http://server.com/https://www.google.com`

Comment: But I thing that nginx will pass all after `.com/` to the $1, won't it.

Comment: I believe (though am not 100% sure) that in your example, $1 would be https://www.google.com

Comment: What is `index.php` supposed to do with `$_GET['q']` ?

Comment: @ghoti: find out if it can connect to it using the protocol specified. That's why the protocol is important.

Comment: It looks like that I don't have to do rewrite at all if I use `REQUEST_URI` in php.

Comment: I meant `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 7):

Well, matzahboy and VBart have already contributed nginx configuration excerpts that correctly show you how to rewrite the URL to a GET variable.  But in order to USE this, you have to interpret the value provided in `$_GET['q']`.  You haven't specified the rules you want to follow, so here's a suggestion.

To be tested in this order:

1. *Valid URL per [RFC2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396) using PHP's Validate Filter*: test with cURL, respond TRUE for HTTP response codes < 400, FALSE for anything else.
2. ***(host.)example.com/path** (missing protocol)*: assume HTTP protocol, test per #1.
3. ***host.example.com** (hostname only)*: same as #2
4. ***example.com** (domain only)*: test as #2, then test as **www.example.com**.
5. *Anything else*: fail.

If that makes sense to you, then the following index.php may get you started:

```
<?php

function http_response($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  $head = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);

  if (!$head) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  if ($httpCode < 400) {
    return $url;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

function test_string($q) {
  if (filter_var($q, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // Matches RFC2396, so let's generate a hit.
    return http_response($q);
  }
  elseif (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}(:[0-9]+)?\/.+$/', $q)) {
    // Matches: (host.)example.com/path
    return http_response("http://" . $q);
  }
  elseif (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+\.){2,}[a-z]{2,}$/', $q)) {
    // Matches: host.example.com
    return http_response("http://" . $q . "/");
  }
  elseif (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/', $q)) {
    // Matches: example.com
    $ret=http_response("http://" . $q . "/");
    if ($ret === FALSE) {
      return http_response("http://www." . $q . "/");
    } else {
      return $ret;
    }
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

$q = $_GET['q'];
//$q = $argv[1]; // for command-line testing

$url = test_string($q);

if ($url === FALSE) {
  printf("<p>The URL <strong>%s</strong> is invalid.</p>\n", $q);
} else {
  printf("<p>The URL is <strong>%s</strong>.</p>\n", $url);
}
```

I don't claim that this is the prettiest or most secure code, but at least it implements an analysis strategy for supplied URLs like:

- `http://example.com/https://www.example.net/foo/bar`,
- `http://example.com/example.org/foo/bar` or
- `http://example.com/example.org`

Note that cURL's gopher support may be broken, and other protocols (which do not return HTTP response codes) are not supported by the code above.  If you need to support protocols other than HTTP and HTTPS, please say so in your question and I'll adjust the PHP accordingly.

Specifically, if you want to be able to check `http://example.com/ping://host.example.net` it wouldn't be hard, but it would have to be coded separately from the bit handled by cURL.

Comment: WoW! Let me test it over the weekend. Looks great. I was thinking of implementing this answer for the checking http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483456/250422 but cURL seems to be more popular... Thank you.

Comment: Yup, cURL is generally recommended for this kind of thing.  It just gives you far more baked-in functionality than anything one could code on one's own in a month.  One proviso though; it DOES require a PHP module which may not be installed by default on your web server.  On Debian/Ubuntu, you would `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`.  On FreeBSD, you would probably `cd /usr/ports/ftp/php5-curl; make install clean`.  If you're having trouble with it, give us some OS details ... or post a question in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).  :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @dynamic;
}

location @dynamic {
    fastcgi_pass backend;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $uri;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      /index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /absolute/path/to/index.php;
}
```

---

The `fastcgi_params` file is bundled with nginx

```
$ cat fastcgi_params

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

And you have access to all these fastcgi environment parameters using built-in `$_SERVER` array in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

---

- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://nginx.org/r/try_files
- http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_param
- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/include
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: What's the difference between your solution and `matzahboy`'s one?

Comment: `matzahboy`'s doesn't work with static files and passes URI as a GET parameter. While mine checks the files first and then passes URI as a FastCGI parameter.

Comment: This is way overkill, then, as the OP stated there was just one file (index.php) and no directory structure under the documentroot.

Comment: @ghoti
If there's just `index.php` then he should remove `location /` and replace `@dynamic` by `/`.

Comment: I cannot make it work. I am getting "No input file specified." It's pointing to php file that works nicely for @matzahboy's solution.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you should also set `SCRIPT_NAME`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: My conf file looks like that and points to the same directory like matzahboy solution but his works. Any idea? `server {
    listen   80;
    server_name isup.server.com;
    access_log /srv/www/playground/isup/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/playground/isup/logs/error.log;


location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $uri;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      /index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRTIP_FILENAME /srv/www/playground/isup/public_html/index.php;

}



}`

Comment: `SCRTIP_FILENAME` doesn't equal to `SCRIPT_FILENAME`

Answer (score 3):

Using matzahboy's nginx code:

```
location / {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1
}
```

along with the following PHP code:

```
$basis = array(
    'scheme' => 'http',
);

$info = array_merge( $base, parse_url( 'www.google.com' ) );

print_r( $info );
```

Which will return something like this for example.com/google.com or example.com/http://google.com/

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [path] => www.google.com )
```

Note that the $base array contains the 'scheme' value of 'http'. This defaults the value of scheme so that you can later do something like

```
$info['scheme'] . '://' . $info['path'];
```

which would result in http://google.com/

Hope this answers your full question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of rewrites? I know only Apache's rules. In Apache I would do it this way:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|admin|images|img|png|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|sitemap\.xml\.gz|sitemap\.kml|robots\.txt|javascripts|style.css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

This will pass everything on to `$_GET['page']` (PHP) except if anything in the URL matches `index.php`, `js`, `css` and others.

If you have any questions, let me know. Hope this helped.